# Button won't center even though align-items: center is used in CSS for div

Tags: html, css, react-button

I have this `div`:

```
<div className="cert-footer">
    <Button
        type="submit"
        primary={true}
        fullWidth={false}
    >
        Confirm
    </Button>
</div>
```

My CSS for this is:

```
.cert-footer {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    align-items: center;
}
```

The button will not center. Instead it displays to the left but the bottom padding of 20px is visible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I think it's worth adding `display: flex;` or `display: grid;` to your `.cert-footer`, probably the former in this case. Fairly sure `align-items` does not work unless the element is flex or grid.

Secondly are you trying to vertical or horizontal align? `align-items` works vertically, `justify-content` and `justify-items` work horizontally by default.

Answer (score 0):

add this CSS to your code

```css
.cert-footer {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
  <div class="cert-footer">
      <Button
          type="submit"
          primary={true}
          fullWidth={false}>
          Confirm
      </Button>
  </div>
```